# Access Linux Root Files from .NetCore app

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, raspberry-pi3, wifi

I have created a .net core app that runs very well on the Raspberry Pi.

I wish to try and connect this device to a wifi router or an access point from an iPhone.

After looking I know you can create a conf file and put it onto the sd card via a card reader.

What I would like to do is allow the user to enter their wifi details via my own interface and for my own c# program to make the chnages.

i have spent sometime but found no examples.

If anyone knows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach for GUI based configuration is not to edit the system config files directly, but to talk through the configuration interface provided by the network daemons.

`wpa_supplicant` can be talked to through the `wpa_cli` utility. You use it by spawning `wpa_cli` as a separate process with stdio redirected into a pipe, into which/from you send the configurations commands.

***Update:** To talk to `wpa_cli` you'd create a process with redirected output. With Mono you'd do it as following*

```
private void start_wpa_cli()
{
    ProcessStartInfo psI = new ProcessStartInfo("wpa_cli");
    psI.UseShellExecute = false;
    psI.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    psI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = psI;
    p.Start();

    StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput;
    sw.AutoFlush = true;
    StreamReader sr = p.StandardOutput;

    ...
```

*You can then send wpa_cli commands through `sw` and read the result from `sr`. The commands for `wpa_cli` you can find in its manpage.*

If `NetworkManager` is used, you talk to it through its D-Bus interface. ***Update:** To access D-Bus from .Net/Mono you could for example use https://github.com/mono/dbus-sharp*

Comment: Thanks do you have any examples please?  Obviously, I am Googling as I type.. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the augmentation. I know how to do pipe redirects - so thanks for that :)  I am more concerned about the step by step instructions.  Also, thanks for the link.  I have been looking at that for the past 30mins.  Been trying to convert to a .Net Core DLL but the libraries are not all supported. My search continues/..

Comment: I am still looking at this.  I think this is the right/best approach for me.  I will update later my results

Comment: many thanks - took me a while to find things but got there i think